# Is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/k^2 = \pi^2/6$ a valid example for the incompleteness of rational numbers?

Tags: rational-numbers

Consider the sequence of partial sums  $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}$. As a finite sum of rational numbers, the $s_n$ itsself are rational. However, since $\pi$ is transcendental, $\pi^2$ is an irrational number.

We can show that $s_n$ is Cauchy and $s_n \to \pi^2/6$, i.e. we have a cauchy sequence lying in $\mathbb{Q}$, which does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is this a valid example, to show the incompleteness of the rational numbers?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes the example chosen when that statement is made is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}$, because the irrationality is [easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4581793/43608), but any rational sequence converging to an irrational number is a valid example.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Even more classic is the sequence (not series) $$\frac{\left\lfloor 10^n\cdot\sqrt2\right\rfloor}{10^n}$$where the irrationality proof is even easier (or at least more universally known and celebrated).

Comment: Yes, it is.  As others have mentioned though, the digital expansion of any irrational number is too.  (Arthur's is example is simply taking the digital expansion of $\sqrt 2$ and looking at it term by term.  I can see how a novice student might think that that is cheating or begging the question but it really isn't.  The subtle thing is, it is because the rationals *are* incomplete but dense, that we know we *can* write any real as a decimal.)

Comment: You don't even need to know the irrationality of a named number to do this. Just use any decimal expansion that is not eventually periodic, such as $0.101001000100001 \ldots$ (continue increasing by one the number of zeros between consecutive $1$'s). No such number is rational because the decimal expansion of any quotient of nonzero integers is eventually periodic, a result that is straightforward from usual grade school long division and [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).